# android honeycomb menu button target

Tags: android, button, menu, target, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am trying to get my app to be backward compatible so i need to show the menu button
since we used the menu button in our app on previous versions.

So I was reading and it says that if your target is 11 (3.0) than you don't get the menu button but it your target is 10 they you do.

But the issue is I am using fragments so my target has to be 11.

Any thoughts.

Comment: My thoughts: Move with the new API, do not try and fight the change to get back old functionality, just work with it.

Comment: What's "menu button"? Can you clarify?

Comment: See this blog post:http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html. Set the target SDK for 14 and the min SDK for whatever else you want. Don't forget to edit the menu.xlm file to add your menu options to the Action Bar. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9440194/1172181

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ordinary options menus will appear regardless of Android version. If you have:

```
android:targetSdkVersion="11"
```

then the options menu will appear in the action bar on Android 3.0+ devices. All items in the options menu will be available when clicking the "overflow" button in the upper-right corner. Your options menu will appear normally on Android 1.x and 2.x devices, even if you have `android:targetSdkVersion="11"` in your `<uses-sdk>` manifest element.

If you overrode the MENU button to have other behavior, you will need to create some other trigger for that behavior for API Level 11 and higher. Overriding the MENU button was never a good idea to begin with, and as you can see, it is even less of a good idea now. I know of no way to get a MENU button on an Android 3.0 device if you have `android:targetSdkVersion="11"`.

Comment: I have the very same issue Mark with at least one user. I don't do anything funky it's just a menu with some options. The target is set to 11 just as you show in your answer and everything works as intended in the emulator. Yet I have at least one reported case where user doesn't see the menu "grid" icon on the action bar. That if by "action bar" you mean black "foot bar" which usually shows "back", "home" and "running apps" icons

Comment: @DroidIn.net: If the targetSdkVersion is set to 11, and the user is running Honeycomb, they won't see a options menu soft button in the system bar. They're not supposed to. The options menu will be in the action bar, upper-right corner of the screen. If you have disabled the action bar, they will be unable to access your menu options.

Comment: Should I set it to 10 instead, would that help? I do indeed have app toolbar disabled.

Comment: @DroinIn.net: If you have no target, or a target < 10, Honeycomb users will get the "classic" options menu, via the "system bar" (the bar at the bottom). And you want to start working on a GUI design that does not get rid of the action bar on Honeycomb.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that worked for me in order to get older Options Menu on Tablet devices was after I used the following:

```
minSdkVersion="11"
targetSdkVersion="10"
```

I think what helps over here is that I am stating to system that app has been tested against API 10 so I get older Options menu.

And because my app is meant for tablets only, keeping minSdkVersion to 11 also prevents it to be installed on the smaller devices. I know, I might still have to see the case of installation for smaller devices having ICS.