# How to show menu button on Android 3.0?

Tags: android

Currently, I use the phone's menu button to trigger a custom event.  On Android 3.0 on the XOOM tablet the menu button does not show. How can I make the button available?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [android honeycomb menu button target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279148/android-honeycomb-menu-button-target)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you just don't target Honeycomb. I.e., android:targetSdkVersion="X" where X is less than 11 (and android:minSdkVersion too!)

This will cause your application to be considered a phone application, and the soft menu button will appear.

You should be asking yourself why you want this functionality on a tablet, though.

Comment: Well the reality is that it's a temp solution to the "custom menu" I have for cellphone.  The custom menu is a different activity.  It's part of the design...

Answer (score 3):

You can also detect whether the MENU button is present with this:

```
ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey()
```

And if not, you can show a custom menu button in your UI.

Answer (score -1):

In your res folder make sure you have a "menu" folder.. inside that folder you will need menu.xml file.....  the xml file should contain information that looks similar to this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

You can change out the item section to reflect your own menu.

Make sure you have the xml file saved...

Then go into your main code and do the following:

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return true;

    }



}
```

that's how I do it.

Comment: This doesn't work...  I'm assuming that there has to be a flag that can be set to allow this button to be shown...

Comment: This solution is for Android versions before 3.0.

Comment: This is not working on Honeycomb and ICS and JellyBean ( just for <3 versions)